# What is IntelliJ doing in the background?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-scala

Recently IntelliJ has gotten very laggy, long pauses, etc.

On my Mac, when I run Activity Monitor, I can see IntelliJ chewing up CPU for some reasons that are not clear. A lot of CPU.

In IntelliJ, I am just trying to edit my code, but it becomes unbearable because typing, scrolling, anything trivial becomes so laggy I cannot work.

Restarting IntelliJ helps for a while, but then the problem is back shortly. What could be going on?

1. Garbage Collection?
2. Some other background process?
3. Scala?

I have autobuild turned off.

Comment: Not a programming question. Try an intellij forum.

Comment: Only a CPU snapshot can tell, refer to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235.

Comment: You can enable Memory Indicator, or try CPU sampling with VisualVM

Answer (score 0):

Moved to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000423410-What-is-IntelliJ-doing-in-the-background-

Sorry about posting here.

Comment: As an aside, someone told me to edit custom properties and add  the experimental setting

    editor.zero.latency.typing=true

and this seems to have helped.